# Maintaining the last N log entries in the log file (circular logging)

Tags: log4net

Does log4net support circular logging? (I think that's the right term.)

I want to maintain the last N entries in a log file. Say N=100. If I have 100 entries and then add a 101st, the desired behavior would be to delete the 1st entry from the top of the file and add the new log entry at the bottom, so that there is always 100 (or fewer) entries, with the oldest entry at the top and the newest at the bottom.

Basically, I want to record a couple of pieces of information to a file every minute. I only am interesting in seeing/keeping the last 100 entries. I could roll my own solution, but I'm already using log4net for logging other issues and was hoping I could use it for this purpose, as well.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Out of the box solution would be `RollingFileAppender` with Size limit. You cannot specify how many entries you want to keep in the file, but if you play with the size (lets say 100KB), you can get what you want.

Here is an example:

```xml
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="0" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

And some documentation about why setting `maxSizeRollBackups` is important in this case:

> If set to zero, then there will be no backup files and the log file
>   will be truncated when it reaches MaxFileSize.

[MaxSizeRollBackups](http://%20https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Appender_RollingFileAppender_MaxSizeRollBackups.htm) [RollingMode](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_RollingFileAppender_RollingMode.htm)

Comment: I tried this approach, but it wasn't circular, at least not as far as I could tell. That is, when the 100KB limit was hit, it created a new, blank log file, rather than deleting content from the start of the file.

Comment: The documentation you shared illustrates my problem - "the log file **will be truncated** when it reaches MaxFileSize." I don't want the log file to truncate - I want the earliest data to be removed to make space for the new data.